# Why do we need to use private variable getters inside the same contract?

Tags: contract-design, openzeppelin

I recently read a smart contract from Openzepplin with the following code in it

```
    uint256 private certainAmount;
    

    function getCertainAmount() public returns (uint256){
        return certainAmount;
    }

    
    function usesCertainAmount() public {
        uint256 calculation = getCertainAmount() + 200;
        /***/
    }
```

as you can see they are using the getter of the private function even inside the same contract, and I can't seem to understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that if those are functions, you can override them in inheriting contracts more easily. If they were just variables in a function, you would need to rewrite the whole function - now you just need to rewrite the variable part.

This is a quite common pattern with OpenZeppelin: they make their contracts "pluggable", so you can easily inject your own functionality in places. They even have sometimes empty function implementations just because of this.